# What does Access DateSerial function return if arguments are not integers

Tags: sql, ms-access, null

I am trying to convert a date in text format to date format, and then use the numeric date for some calculations.

Here is part of my query:

```
DateSerial(right(a.exit_date,4), left(a.exit_date,2), mid(a.exit_date,4,2)) as exit_date_num, 
IIF(not(exit_date_num is NULL), date1,date2) as hire_date
```

This code works when exit_date contains some values like "11/26/2012". However sometimes exit_date is missing (takes a value of space, that is " "). In that case my IIF condition   (2nd line of code above) does not work. However if I change first line to following, it works

```
IIF(exit_date<> " ",DateSerial(right(a.exit_date,4), left(a.exit_date,2), mid(a.exit_date,4,2))) as exit_date_num, 
IIF(not(exit_date_num is NULL), date1,date2) as hire_date
```

So apparently when DateSerial encounters invalid arguments it is returning something which is not null. I want to know what it is. 
The final purpose of is to create a generic code which can successfully create a hire_date irrespective of whether exit_date is blank/ one space/ two spaces.

Comment: I have got the generic solution by changing the codes to single line query: IIF(IsDate(exit_date), date1,date2) as hire_date. However I would still like to understand what happens when the arguments of a function are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateSerial always returns a date, thus your `exit_date_num is NULL` will never be true.

Though it is not quite clear what you attempt to do, I would use *IsDate*:

```
IIf(IsDate(a.exit_date), date1, date2) As hire_date
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav, so how do I determine for which records query has returned a missing date.

Answer (score 2):

DateSerial accepts integer variables as parameters. When you use as parameter expression like `right(a.exit_date,4)`, Access calculates this expression as string and then tries to convert string to integer. As soon as empty string cannot be converted to integer, function generates error 13 (Type mismatch) and query fails

Comment: thanks @sergey, so how do we determine for which records query has generated error 13.

Comment: Just modify your query, add where condition `IsDate(a.exit_date)=false`. Query will show all invalid records.